# Empty alert with ajax request despite returned string

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using jQuery to send an ajax request and even though it's triggering 'success' the alert 'msg' is empty. The alert pop-up comes us, but it's empty.

I've used nearly identical function elsewhere on the same page/controller without issue. Thanks for any insights on this.

Jquery:

```
$('#inputScale').change(function() {


    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : '<?php echo site_url('resume/change_scale'); ?>',
        data: {
        resume_id : '<?php echo $this->session->userdata('resume_id'); ?>',                             
        inputScale: $('#inputScale').val()
        },
        success : function(msg){
        alert(msg);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('failure');
        }
    }); 

});
```

PHP excerpt:

```
public function change_scale()
{
    return "TEST";
}
```

Comment: Please edit your post and include the results of your XHR return using Firebug or Chrome, or your favorite debugging tool.

Comment: Does the PHP script actually *echo* the variable, or just *returns* it? That's different AFAIK.

Comment: first place to start with ajax is look in browser console at what actually gets sent from server...looks like nothing will be sent

Comment: Will do. @GuillaumePoussel -- I was having issues with post variables and instead of 'return'ing tried a variable. Great point, let me try echo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using jQuery's .ajax() method, it calls a page and on success, allows you to handle the **output** (i.e. what would be displayed on that page if you called it directly in your browser).

In your case, you are just doing a return from the function which won't work as you expect. Try this instead:

```
public function change_scale()
{
   echo("TEST");
}
```

When the function is done echoing, it sends *TEST* back to jQuery which is handled in your `success: function(msg){ alert(msg); }` section.

Answer (score 0):

Try a console.dir(msg) and see what you receive exactly.

Regards,
Denis R.